# Accessing multiple ids bug in a loop

Tags: php, javascript

I have a small problem/bug in my error box thing. I'll show you the code first and then the explanation:
Where I call the function:

```
$jsid = 0;
    foreach ($errors as &$value) {
        $jsid++;
        echo $jsid;
        error('', $value, $jsid);
    }
```

...and this is the function:

```
function error($title, $error, $id)
{
    echo "<div id='warning".$id."' class='errorbox' style='border-style:solid; border-width: 1px; border-color:#FFF;'>
            <a style='float: left;' onClick='document.getElementById('warning".$id."').style.display = 'none';' aria-label='Exit View As...'  class='_7fy'></a>";
            if($title !== '') {
               echo "<h3>$title</h3>";
            }
            echo "<p>$error</p></div>";
}
```

What I did was that because I knew I would have multiple elements with the same ID, I added the foreach so that they would be different and then in the function, I would add the id i pass in to the 'warning'. The way I saw it, was that it would ensure that the JS onclick worked. Would it be possible for someone to explain what is wrong. A fix would be well appreciated and save a lot of headbanging on the keyboard.

Comment: What is the problem you are having exactly?  The code seems to look fine...

Comment: Would it be possible to say, what actually fails?

Comment: The javascript doesn't seem to work. That is when I click on it.

Comment: What browser do you use?  Can you copy/paste the view source of a generated example page (the browser's HTML, not the source code) into a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can see it?

Comment: The only wrong thing I see is that you are not encoding HTML markup for the output variables properly. See http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/ and http://php.net/faq.html

Comment: You'll need to properly escape the quotes. Just look at the rendered html, and you'll notice that this is not the case. (`onClick='document.getElementById('warning1').style.display = 'none';'`)

Comment: Then give us the rendered HTML output.

Comment: What are you trying to click on? As I can see, your `a` tag is empty and will not be visible

Comment: Have you tested your script using the browsers debug console? My guess is that the javasript generated is invalid (using `'` without escaping for instance).

Comment: F12 to the rescue!!! Please post console messages (or in this case read the console messages, hit yourself and fix the "unterminated literals")

Comment: HTML output: http://pastebin.com/9mYmzKjd

Comment: Got it fixed, guys! FAngles solution seems to have worked ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
onClick="this.style.display = 'none'; return false;"
```

This is easier, no?

EDIT: I agree with FAngel to be more precise:

```
onClick="this.parentNode.style.display = 'none'; return false;"
```

Comment: This will result in hidden a, but div will stay visible. Or, if you put it on div - whole div will became active and any click on it will hide whole message.

Answer (score 2):

You've got a fundamental quoting problem. Mixing **THREE** different languages, and trying to make it work. You're in PHP mode, dumping out html, which contains javascript, and all use the same quotes for the same thing. Instead of such ugly junk, use a [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc), or at least remove PHP from the mix, so you're down to just html+js, e.g:

```
echo <<<EOL
<div id="warning{$id}" class="errorbox" style="border-style:solid; border-width: px; border-color:#FFF;">
    <a style="float: left;" onClick="document.getElementById('warning{$id}').style.display = 'none';" aria-label="Exit View As..."  class="_7fy"></a>

EOL
```

-- or --

```
?>
<div id="warning<?php echo $id ?>" class="errorbox" style="border-style:solid; border-width: px; border-color:#FFF;">
    <a style="float: left;" onClick="document.getElementById('warning<?php echo $id ?>}').style.display = 'none';" aria-label="Exit View As..."  class="_7fy"></a>

<?php
```

Note how the quotes just "naturally" work, without requiring any escapes.

Comment: does that work in a function?

Comment: yes. you can break in/out of php mode anytime. and heredocs can be used anywhere echo or string assignments are used, e.g. `$var = <<<EOL blah blah blah EOL` is valid.

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem:

```
onClick='document.getElementById('warning".$id."').style.display = 'none';'
        ^                        ^ - the string ends here
```

You've got single quotes (`'`) nested inside single quotes, which is an error, and causes the `onClick` string to terminate early.  You'll need to change one of them to double quotes.

```
onClick=\"document.getElementById('warning".$id."').style.display = 'none';\"
        ^^ change to double-quotes, and escape for being inside PHP quote. ^^
```

Answer (score 1):

try to format your onclick part like below:

```
onClick=\"document.getElementById('warning".$id."').style.display = 'none';\"
```

So, there will be no mess with closing quotes

Also, instead of using ID, you can use  parentNode (no need to assign IDs at all, **but** if you wrap, for instance, your `a` tag with some other element - this part will became broken):

```
onClick=\"this.parentNode.style.display = 'none';\"
```

In case of your markup, parentNode will point to a div which you need to close. And this in event handlers points to an element where event happened.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.parentNode